# How do I write a function to convert duration to time in milliseconds and account for invalid values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, duration, milliseconds

I'm using Rails 5 with Ruby 2.4.  I want to convert a string, which represents duration (time) to milliseconds, so I have this function

```
  def duration_in_milliseconds(input)
    if input && input.count("a-zA-Z ") == 0 
      if input.index(".") && !input.index(":")
        input.gsub!(/\./, ':')
      end
      # replace bizarre apostraphes where they intended ":"'s
      input.gsub!(/'/, ':')  
      # Strip out unnecessary white space 
      input.gsub!(/\A\p{Space}+|\p{Space}+\z/, '')  
      input.split(':').map(&:to_f).inject(0) { |a, b| a * 60 + b } * 1000
    else
      0
    end
  end
```

This works great for strings like "6:52" (6 mintues, 52 seconds), but also works for things like "52:6" (which is invalid, "52:06" would be correct).  I wish to have the function return zero if someone enters in a single digit in any spot other than the first number before the ":".  How do I do this?  NOte that I still want a duration like "15:24.8" to parse normally (that is 15 minutes, 24 seconds, and eight tenths of a second).

Comment: Is the minutes place required, or is `5.678` a valid input?

Comment: Hi, Yes, "5.678" is valid.  Good point.

Comment: Your current code appears to allow `.` as a delimiter in place of `:`. In that case, is `1.23` one minute and 23 seconds, or 1.23 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to come up with a solution for this and ended up reworking the code.

I started splitting the string and removing all the white space. To remove the white space first I ensure that there's no leading nor trailing white space and then I incorporate any amount of extra space before or after the `:` characters.

Then I assign the values returned from the split to 3 variables I named `hr`, `min` and `seg`. If you're unfamiliar with this, the variables are filled out from left to right and, in case there aren't enough elements, the remaining vars get a `nil`.

Then, the condition. For this I say: "Return zero if either `min` or `seg` don't match two consecutive numeric characters while being present"

And finally, I sum their respective values in seconds, which returns the numer of seconds. And at the end of the line I convert it to milliseconds by multiplying it by 1000

```
def duration_in_milliseconds(input)
  hr, min, seg = input.strip.split(/\s*:\s*/)
  return 0 if [min, seg].any? {|value| value && !(value =~ /\d\d/)}
  (hr.to_i * 60 * 60 + min.to_i * 60 +  seg.to_i) * 1000
end
```

And I tried it out on a bunch of strings to make sure it worked.

```
duration_in_milliseconds("0:00:01")             # => 1000
duration_in_milliseconds("0:01:01")             # => 61000
duration_in_milliseconds("1:01:01")             # => 3661000
duration_in_milliseconds("0:15")                # => 900000
duration_in_milliseconds("1:   05")             # => 3900000
duration_in_milliseconds("1:5")                 # => 0
duration_in_milliseconds("1:5 ")                # => 0
duration_in_milliseconds(" \t 1 : 05  : 15   ") # => 3915000
duration_in_milliseconds("1:5:15")              # => 0
duration_in_milliseconds("1")                   # => 3600000
duration_in_milliseconds("1:5D:15")             # => 0
```

I hope it helped and answered the question (in some way), if not, please don't hessitate to ping me.

Cheers

Fede